# Any good usb-serial (RS485) adapter to use with GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb-device

I'm having problem with usb-serial (RS485) adapters.

Firstly, I tried ch341 without success. The problem in this case is the linux driver, made by reverse engeneering (sadly without any help from the company). At Windows it works great.

So I changed to FTDI (FT232BL) but, despite "working", it fails consistently, erroring a bit in one byte from time to time and this prevents its use. But, i think it is not linux driver fault because errors happen at Windows also.

So do you recommend any good usb-serial (RS485) adapter to use with GNU/Linux?

Comment: maybe your ftdi adapter is just bad? did you try more than one?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another FTDI adapter in my hands. =(